# ¿Como llamar un Store Procedure que retorne una lista de datos en Entity Framework Code First?

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedure, entity-framework-6

Necesito mostrar una lista en un DataGridView pero debido a la complejidad de la consulta SQL prefiero no usar Lin-Q así que cree un procedimiento almacenado pero ya que uso el Entity Framework no quiero llamar usando SQLConnection sino desde DbContext.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para usar procedimientos almacenados llama al método `Database.SqlQuery` aqui tu pasas una clase `TElement` con los nombres de las columnas que devuelve el procedimiento almacenado y luego pasas los parametros un ejemplo:

```
 public List<Persona> RetornarListado(string nombres, string apellidos) {
      using(var db = new NameContext()) {
           var listado = db.Database.SqlQuery<Persona>(
               "SPObtenerPersonas @filtronombres, @filtroapellidos",
               new SqlParameter("@filtronombres", nombres),
               new SqlParameter("@filtroapellidos", apellidos));//aquí usas el método
           return listado.ToList();
      }
 }
```